# Apply rigid body physics to armature

Tags: rigging, armature, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have a fully rigged human character and want this guy to lay flat on a cube with the back. The lower legs should be pulled downwards by gravity at the knees.
[image]

How can I add physics to the armature itself, not the whole object as one body?

Comment: sounds like a job for hooking

Comment: I am not able to add hooks to the armature itself, right?

Comment: i don't think so, but you can parent the vertex groups from the armature to rigid bodies.